# How to know the i th value of button which has max length text in the if statement

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have function here which loop through the the `button` and find there `innerHTML` length.

I tried to use `Math.max` to find max length value but couldn't as the result is showing the last value only .
As you can see from code used a loop, how to know the value of `i` which has max value (here also last value is printed)

```js
function widthBtn() {
  var reed = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0].getElementsByTagName("BUTTON");
  var reed1 = document.getElementsByClassName("demo")

  for (let i = 0; i < reed.length; i++) {
    reed1[i].innerHTML = reed[i].innerHTML.length
    document.getElementById("demon1").innerHTML = Math.max(reed[i].innerHTML.length)
    if (reed[i].innerHTML.length == Math.max(reed[i].innerHTML.length)) {
      document.getElementById("demon").innerHTML = i;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("demon").innerHTML = "no"
    }
  }
}
widthBtn();
```

```css
.container {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between
}

button {
  width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!--span tag is used which act as container for button to preserve the button default height can remove it to span the whole height of container by button-->
  <button>This text is way more long than the other (very right)</button>
  <button>Little text (very left)</button>
</div>
<span>Length of text in 1st btn : <span class="demo"></span></span><br>
<span>Length of text in 2nd btn : <span class="demo"></span></span><br>
<span>Highest length of btn : <span id="demon1"></span></span><br>
<span>ith position of highest value : <span id="demon"></span></span><br>
```

Comment: Did you use `innerText` or `textContent` instead of `innerHtml` ? May be it helps I am not sure :)

Comment: Length is alright as you can see `54` & `23` are printed but highest value and position values are wrong

Comment: Showing the last values entered in loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Math.max incorrectly here. Math.max returns the largest number passed to it from a list of arguments. You're only passing one of the lengths to it at a time, so it will always return the value of that one number, making your if statement always evaluate to true.

Instead, you can put all of the lengths into an array and use Math.max to find the largest value in that array.

```
let lengths = Array.from(reed).map(e => e.innerHTML.length);
let max = Math.max(...lengths);
document.getElementById("demon1").innerHTML = max;
```

```js
function widthBtn() {
  var reed = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0].getElementsByTagName("BUTTON");
  var reed1 = document.getElementsByClassName("demo")
  
  let lengths = Array.from(reed).map(e => e.innerHTML.length);
  let max = Math.max(...lengths);
  document.getElementById("demon1").innerHTML = max;

  for (let i = 0; i < reed.length; i++) {
    reed1[i].innerHTML = reed[i].innerHTML.length
    if (reed[i].innerHTML.length == max) {
      document.getElementById("demon").innerHTML = i;
    } 
  }
}
widthBtn();
```

```css
.container {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between
}

button {
  width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!--span tag is used which act as container for button to preserve the button default height can remove it to span the whole height of container by button-->
  <button>This text is way more long than the other (very right)</button>
  <button>Little text (very left)</button>
</div>
<span>Length of text in 1st btn : <span class="demo"></span></span><br>
<span>Length of text in 2nd btn : <span class="demo"></span></span><br>
<span>Highest length of btn : <span id="demon1"></span></span><br>
<span>ith position of highest value : <span id="demon"></span></span><br>
```

Comment: Can you tell about `let lengths = Array.from(reed).map(e => e.innerHTML.length);` and `Math.max(...lengths);` , how they are working here

Comment: `Array.from(reed)` creates an Array from the HTMLCollection `reed`. `.map(e => e.innerHTML.length)` then iterates through that array and returns a new array containing just the length value of each element in the array. Finally, `...lengths` uses the [spread operator (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to turn the array (lengths) into a list of arguments passed into the `Math.max` function.

Comment: is `.map` taking that value from reed array and what `e` acts here as some variable form which take value from array

Comment: You should read up on Array.map, as well as Array.filter and Array.reduce. They are quite useful. `e => e.innerHTML.length` is what's called a lambda function and `Array.map(e => { })` is a loop through the array. Each element is passed into the function as `e`. I like to call this parameter `e`, but you can call it anything. The part to the right of the arrow is the function body. I'm using a shorthand return here by not using braces, so the function just returns the length of the innerHTML. `Array.map` returns a new array with the return values of that function for each element in the array.

Comment: Thanks very much @David

Comment: You're very welcome.